# Applications of polynomials of a high degree

Tags: polynomials, applications

What is the highest polynomial degree that has an application in real life, and what is that application? My google search yielded 3rd degree at most.

Comment: This is a fuzzy question, depending on what you call real life. (Many people live without ever using polynomials.) In engineering and scientific circles, higher degree polynomials are certainly in use, with a frequency that decreases with the degree. Mathematicians can play with polynomials of thousands of terms... There is no "highest".

Comment: Eigenvalue problems in physics can be (informally) considered to be searching for roots of infinite-degree polynomials. Guess it will be hard to find a finite upper bound.

Comment: Stefan-Boltzmann's law (quartic) must b e a candidate for most frequent actual evaluation of higher-than-cubic polynomial outside formal polynomials and function expansions / transforms.

Comment: @dannie The expression of the Van der Walls forces has a factor in $R^7$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Lennard-Jones potential has even $R^{12}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Practitioners in signal and image processing heavily use the so-called Discrete Fourier Transform, which is a polynomial evaluated on complex variables. Applications in medical imaging abound.

The degree of these polynomials typically reaches the image size, which can be like 4096 or  much more.

---

Other consumers of polynomials are the error correction methods (such as those used in digital communication or CD readers). They are implemented in some types of barcodes, with degrees that reach dozens. If I am right, the QR codes use up to degree 69.

Comment: A good one. IIRC the error correcting code used in CDs uses polynomials up to degree 28.

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic polynomial of any matrix (though rarely explicitly computed) gives quite a bit of information about that matrix that is incredibly useful in a huge variety of data analysis settings (machine learning, dimensionality reduction, etc.) The degree of this polynomial is the same as the size of the matrix (depending on setting, this can easily be in the multiple thousands, or even larger). Admittedly this is more of a computer science answer than math, but is still relevant.